# Strong_parameters in view with mixed models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I am using strong parameters and when I try to save the following form I get the following message.

undefined method `household_params' for # '<'VisitsController:0x007fa88deec428'>'

I am confused because I am using the visits controller and not the households controller - The visit is associated with a household as shown below and I call the view with the following code:

```
= link_to 'New Visit', {controller: 'visits', action: 'new', 
household_id: household.id, method: 'post'}, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

The Form is:

```
%h3 Household: #{household.name}
%h4 Household Members: #{household.neighbors.count}
%h4 Visits: #{household.visits.count}
= simple_form_for visit do |f|
  = f.input  :visited_on,     :label => 'Visited On', as: :date_picker, input_html: { class: 'span2' }
  = f.input  :starch,         :label => false,  collection: ['Beans','Rice','Potatoes'],selected: 'Beans'
  = f.input  :cereal,         :label => false,  collection: ['Cereal','Grits','Oatmeal']
  = f.input  :option1,        :label => false,  collection: ['Peanut Butter Jelly', 'Deserts','Baby Fromula'], prompt: 'Options'
  = f.input  :items_received, :label => 'Special Needs',input_html: {rows: 4, class: 'span9' }
  = f.input  :notes,          :label => 'Notes',input_html: {rows: 4, class: 'span9' }
  = f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary', :label=> 'Save'
```

The form works fine without the three lines that display information about the household

I am thinking strong_parameters is getting confused